# forEach Loop Only Accounting for First Iteration of Condition

Tags: javascript, html, foreach

My goal is get all of the data results that my forEach is looping through to post to the correct `<li>` based on the filter condition. All the data objects within the array with the criteria equaling that of the condition, I want to post within the `<ol></ol>` as a `<li>` element. I thought my structure was correct, but it is only posting the first instance. Do I need another forEach within my condition?

Here is a live example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  var equipRequestData = [
    {
      "Title" : "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee" : "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem" : "www.google.com",
      "Status" : "Open",
      "Type" : "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title" : "Beerus New Keyboard Request",
      "Employee" : "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem" : "www.google.com",
      "Status" : "Closed",
      "Type" : "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title" : "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee" : "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem" : "www.google.com",
      "Status" : "Open",
      "Type" : "Help"
    },
    {
      "Title" : "Trunks New Monitor Request",
      "Employee" : "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem" : "www.google.com",
      "Status" : "Closed",
      "Type" : "Help"
    },
  ]

  var currUserId = "Beerus";


  function sortEquipReq(equipRequestData){
    const requests = equipRequestData;

    const openEquip = [];
    const closedEquip = [];
    const openHelp = [];
    const closedHelp = [];

    requests.forEach((request) => {
        console.log(request)
      let type = request.Type;
      let user = request.Employee;
      let status = request.Status;
      if (type === "Equipment" && user === currUserId && status === "Open") {
        $('#openEquipmentReq').html('<li><a href= "'+ request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
      /* if (type === "Equipment" && user === currUserId && status === "Closed") {
        $('#closedEquipmentReq').html('<li><a href= "'+ request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
      if (type === "Help" && user === currUserId && status === "Open") {
        $('#openHelpReq').html('<li><a href= "'+ request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
      if (type === "Help" && user === currUserId && status === "Closed") {
        $('#closedHelpReq').html('<li><a href= "'+ request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      } */
    })
  }
  sortEquipReq(equipRequestData);
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active1");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
      panel.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
    } 
  });
}

});
```

```css
    .accordion {
      background-color: #104723;
      color: white;
      cursor: pointer;
      padding: 18px;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      text-align: center;
      outline: none;
      font-size: 15px;
      transition: 0.4s;
    }

    .accordion:hover {
      background-color: #0e3f1f;
    }

    .active1:after {
      content: "\2796"; /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
    }

    .accordion:after {
      content: '\002B';
      color: white;
      font-weight: bold;
      float: right;
      margin-left: 5px;
    }

    .panel {
      padding: 0 18px;
      background-color: #ffff;
      max-height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div class="col">
        <button class="accordion">Open Equipment Requests</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <ol id="openEquipmentReq">

          </ol>
        </div>
        <button class="accordion">Closed Equipment Requests</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <ol id="closedEquipmentReq">

          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col justify-content-center mx-4">
        <button class="accordion">Open Help Requests</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <ol id="openHelpReq">

          </ol>
        </div>
        <button class="accordion">Closed Help Requests</button>
        <div class="panel">
          <ol id="closedHelpReq">

          </ol>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are overwriting the html of the list instead of appending to it. This can be fixed by doing (e.g.)

```
$('#openEquipmentReq').append(<new HTML>)
```

You can also simplify your `sortEquipReq` function by building a selector from the request type and status instead of having an `if` for each pair:

```
function sortEquipReq(equipRequestData) {
  equipRequestData.forEach((request) => {
    let type = request.Type;
    let user = request.Employee;
    let status = request.Status;
    if (user === currUserId) {
      let list = $('#' + status.toLowerCase() + type + 'Req')
      list.append('<li><a href= "' + request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
    }
  })
}
```

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var equipRequestData = [{
      "Title": "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Open",
      "Type": "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus New Keyboard Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Closed",
      "Type": "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus Broken Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Open",
      "Type": "Help"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Trunks Broken Keyboard Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Closed",
      "Type": "Help"
    },
  ]

  var currUserId = "Beerus";


  function sortEquipReq(equipRequestData) {
    equipRequestData.forEach((request) => {
      let type = request.Type;
      let user = request.Employee;
      let status = request.Status;
      if (user === currUserId) {
        let list = $('#' + status.toLowerCase() + type + 'Req')
        list.append('<li><a href= "' + request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
    })
  }
  sortEquipReq(equipRequestData);
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active1");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #104723;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #0e3f1f;
}

.active1:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="accordion">Open Equipment Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="openEquipmentReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
      <button class="accordion">Closed Equipment Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="closedEquipmentReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col justify-content-center mx-4">
      <button class="accordion">Open Help Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="openHelpReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
      <button class="accordion">Closed Help Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="closedHelpReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are only setting `.html()` of element instead of adding to it. If you must use this method, then try `x.innerHTML += str_html`;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var equipRequestData = [{
      "Title": "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Open",
      "Type": "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus New Keyboard Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Closed",
      "Type": "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Open",
      "Type": "Help"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Trunks New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Closed",
      "Type": "Help"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Open",
      "Type": "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus New Keyboard Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Closed",
      "Type": "Equipment"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Beerus New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Open",
      "Type": "Help"
    },
    {
      "Title": "Trunks New Monitor Request",
      "Employee": "Beerus",
      "LinkToItem": "www.google.com",
      "Status": "Closed",
      "Type": "Help"
    }    
  ];

  var currUserId = "Beerus";


  function sortEquipReq(equipRequestData) {
    const requests = equipRequestData;

    const openEquip = [];
    const closedEquip = [];
    const openHelp = [];
    const closedHelp = [];

    requests.forEach((request) => {
      // console.log(request)
      let type = request.Type;
      let user = request.Employee;
      let status = request.Status;
      if (type === "Equipment" && user === currUserId && status === "Open") {
        $('#openEquipmentReq')[0].innerHTML += ('<li><a href= "' + request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
      if (type === "Equipment" && user === currUserId && status === "Closed") {
        $('#closedEquipmentReq')[0].innerHTML += ('<li><a href= "' + request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
      if (type === "Help" && user === currUserId && status === "Open") {
        $('#openHelpReq')[0].innerHTML += ('<li><a href= "' + request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
      if (type === "Help" && user === currUserId && status === "Closed") {
        $('#closedHelpReq')[0].innerHTML += ('<li><a href= "' + request.LinkToItem + '">' + request.Title + '</a></li>');
      }
    })
  }
  sortEquipReq(equipRequestData);
  var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
  var i;

  for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active1");
      var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
      if (panel.style.maxHeight) {
        panel.style.maxHeight = null;
      } else {
        panel.style.maxHeight = panel.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    });
  }

});
```

```css
.accordion {
  background-color: #104723;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #0e3f1f;
}

.active1:after {
  content: "\2796";
  /* Unicode character for "minus" sign (-) */
}

.accordion:after {
  content: '\002B';
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: #ffff;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.12.9/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
    <div class="col">
      <button class="accordion">Open Equipment Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="openEquipmentReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
      <button class="accordion">Closed Equipment Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="closedEquipmentReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col justify-content-center mx-4">
      <button class="accordion">Open Help Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="openHelpReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
      <button class="accordion">Closed Help Requests</button>
      <div class="panel">
        <ol id="closedHelpReq">

        </ol>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

[`.html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) sets the HTML content, overwriting what was in there before.

What you want is [`.append()`](https://api.jquery.com/append/).